# How to pass textbox value to JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, asp.net

How to pass two textbox values to a javascript function on a button click event.I have tried it like this but it is not working.here is my code

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="lnkBTNSubmit" runat="server" CssClass="buttonlink"
  OnClientClick="checkDateRange(GetTextBoxValue('<%= txtATrendStartDate.ClientID %>'.value),GetTextBoxValue('<%= txtATrendEndDate.ClientID %>'.value))">Submit</asp:LinkButton>
```

and

```
function checkDateRange(start, end)
{
}
```

Any Suggestion?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something like this would do the trick

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="lnkBTNSubmit" runat="server" CssClass="buttonlink"
  OnClientClick="return onBtnSubmitClick()">Submit</asp:LinkButton>

function onBtnSubmitClick(){
   var start = document.getElementById('<%= txtATrendStartDate.ClientID %>').value;
   var end = document.getElementById('<%= txtATrendEndDate.ClientID %>').value;
   return checkDateRange(start, end);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

do it in your inline/header javascript like this:

```
var element = document.getElementById('<%= txtATrendEndDate.ClientID %>');

element.value
```

and if you set `ClientIDMode="Static"`
 you can do:

```
var value= document.getElementById('txtATrendEndDate').value;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're missing document.getElementById.

So something like:

```
document.getElementById('<%=txtATrendStartDate.ClientID%>').value
```